# Applying integral substitution rule to $ \int \frac{mx+n}{ax+b} \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: integration, analysis

While I was doing the exercises on the whole I came across this kind of exercises:$$\int \frac{mx+n}{ax+b} \mathrm{d}x $$, my book, I also wrote the execution of my book that is:
$$\int \frac{mx+n}{ax+b} \mathrm{d}x=\frac{m}{a}\int \mathrm{d}x + \frac{na-mb}{a^2}\int \frac{a}{ax+b}\mathrm{d}x= \frac{m}{a}x+ \frac{na-mb}{ a^2}\log|ax+b|+C $$

You could explain to me why these steps ? I did not understand how make to get to that result!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's really just a matter of seeing that:

$$\frac{mx+n}{ax+b} = \frac{m}{a} + \frac{na-bm}{ax+b}$$

Then letting $u=ax+b$ to integrate this.

Comment: but what is the formula you used to factorize it?

Comment: Use long division to divide mx + n by ax + b. The quotient is m/a and the remainder is na - bm.

Answer (score 0):

Going from the first step to the second is polynomial division.

Going from the second step to the third, a substitution $x' = ax+b$ and $dx' = a \centerdot dx$ was made to evaluate the second term.