# How to calculate $\int\frac{x}{ax+b}$ dx

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

How to calculate $\int\frac{x}{ax+b}$ dx ?

I know $\int\frac{1}{ax+b}$ dx but when there is $x$ at the numerator, I don't know where to begin

Comment: [Divide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division) $\frac{x}{ax+b}=\frac{1}{a}+\frac{-b/a}{ax+b}$. So, $\int\frac{x}{ax+b}=\frac{1}{a}\int1-\frac{b}{a}\int\frac{1}{ax+b}$

Comment: Duplicate of [Applying integral substitution rule to $\int \frac{mx+n}{ax+b} \mathrm{d}x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/600142/applying-the-substitution-rule-for-integrals)

Comment: there is NO reason to downvote this question. The duplicate is a generalization of this problem but it does NOT justify the -3 downvotes here. There is Much more Unreasonable to downvote these answers. They are absolutely right.

Comment: @AkutaHinako I agree with you, unfortunately there is a restict group of users which use downvoting as a punitive action against questions they don't like. Often after closure the questions are deleted.

Comment: @AkutaHinako For more information on the different point of views visit [CRUDE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2165/crude), [GENTLE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97476/gentle). You can also raise a question on Meta on this in order to have an advice from other users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

We have

$$\frac{x}{ax+b}=\frac1a\frac{ax+b-b}{ax+b}=\frac1a-\frac1a\frac{b}{ax+b}$$

or by parts

$$\int\frac{x}{ax+b}dx=\frac1ax\ln(ax+b)-\frac1a\int\ln(ax+b)dx$$

Comment: there is NO reason to downvote this. It’s absolutely right.

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite $I=\int\frac x{ax+b} dx$ as $I=\frac 1a\int\frac {ax}{ax+b} dx$

Then $I=\frac 1a\int\frac {ax+b-b}{ax+b} dx=\frac 1a\int \left( \frac {ax+b}{ax+b}- \frac {b}{ax+b}\right) dx =\frac 1a\int \left( 1- \frac {b}{ax+b}\right) dx$

You should be OK from there.

Comment: there is NO reason to downvote this. It’s absolutely right.